# Using instance attributes to create images in tkinter

Tags: python, oop, canvas, tkinter

I'm working on a simple tkinter program, and am trying to create a callback function that will take an image (imported using PIL and stored as a class attribute) and draw it on the canvas when the corresponding button is clicked. Each click should create a new Bacteria object, reflected by the creation of a new image on the canvas (in the actual program, the new objects are also appended to an array and used later in the program's execution--the code here is something of a simplification).

The following runs without errors (except for a file-not-found error stemming from the fake file name used for posting)  but, unfortunately, no images draw on the canvas when the button is clicked. The code works as intended when the image is imported and stored as an attribute of the MainWindow class--it only seems to fail when imported/stored as an attribute of the Bacteria class.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background = "white")
        self.pack()
        self.canvas_height = 500
        self.canvas_width = 1000
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, height = self.canvas_height, width = self.canvas_width)
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.launch_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Haz clic!", width = 25, command = self.callback)
        self.launch_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "W")


    def callback(self):
        test_bact = Bacteria()
        x_pos = random.randint(0,1000)
        y_pos = random.randint(0,500)
        self.canvas.create_image(x_pos, y_pos, image = test_bact.imageTk)


class Bacteria:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = Image.open('testBacterium.png')
        self.imageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.image)


root = tk.Tk()
app = MainWindow(root)
app.mainloop()
```

I'm sort of stumped on this. Can anyone offer any insight on what's going wrong?

Comment: test_bact is local to the function and so is garbage collected, and of course everything in the class disappears as well.  Use self.test_bact so it remains after the function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation of `canvas.create_image()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method) -

> create_image(position, **options) [#] Draws an image on the canvas.
>
> image= The image object. This should be a PhotoImage or BitmapImage,
> or a compatible object (such as the PIL PhotoImage). **The application
> must keep a reference to the image object.**

(Emphasis mine)

So most probably, either canvas object does not keep a reference to the image itself, or it keeps a *weak reference* . In either case, in a nutshell what is happening is that after to call `canvas.create_image()` and the `callback()` method ends, you are no longer holding any reference to the image object (used in the `create_image()` method) , and hence its not showing up.

In your case, when you are keeping the reference to the image in `Bacteria` class , what is happening is -

1. You are creating the Bacteria object and loading the image and storing there. You are just creating the Bacteria object - `test_bact` - as a local variable for `callback()` method.
2. Then you are using `test_bact.imageTk` for the `image` argument to `canvas.create_image()` method.
3. Now, the `callback()` ends, and hence there is no longer any reference to `test_bact` and so it gets garbage collected. Also , since the only reference to `imageTk` object was in the Bacteria object, that also gets garbage collected, and hence there are no more references to the image object in your application.

---

From what you want to achieve, it seems like you should store the bacteria object as an instance variable of `MainWindows` class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Totally clarified my idea of how the canvas works.